# Adding Trusted Certificate Authority for Apps targeting Android N

Tags: android, certificate, truststore, android-7.0-nougat

As per Android N [documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#default_trusted_ca) -

> By default, apps that target Android N only trust system-provided certificates and no longer trust user-added Certificate Authorities (CA). Apps targeting Android N that wish to trust user-added CAs should use the Network Security Config to specify how user CAs should be trusted.

What I understood from the doc is that user installed certificates will no longer be trusted from Android N. So there should be a way to make it trust. Doc says you can specify the network sec config in manifest file like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
  <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
               ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

And then specify the network config -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

But this is obviously static data. I am interested to know if there is a way to add certificates in trust store dynamically as in real scenarios will have dynamic certs and expiry scenarios. Docs did not clear these for me.

Q1. Any thought or suggestions on how to achieve dynamic addition of trusted certs?

Q2. Does this also affect other certs like wifi certs which may not be app specific? How to trust a custom wifi cert then? How to add it it native trust store?

Comment: "Any thought or suggestions on how to achieve dynamic addition of trusted certs?" -- the Android N network security configuration does not handle this scenario. You are welcome to poke around the `RootTrustManager` in [my backport](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity) and see if you can rig up something that way. "Does this also affect other certs like wifi certs which may not be app specific?" -- no.

Comment: @CommonsWare in Android N we cannot add certificate to native trust store ri8? Is there a way to add with APIs?

Comment: I do not know what you consider the "native trust store" to be. If you mean where the user adds certs, I think only the user can do that (via Settings), and adding system-wide certs is why Android N ignores them by default. If you mean the system-supplied root certs, that cannot be modified. I assume that the expectation is that you will create your own `TrustManager` to implement your rules. Bear in  mind that "dynamic certs and expiry scenarios" creates security issues (e.g., how will you securely get that information to the device?) that you will need to work out.

Comment: Yes exactly I am talking about user added certs. For example vpn or wifi certs. Since Android N these will not be permitted I am thinking of alternate ways. So can the certificates provided in network security config used to configure wifi/vpn or is there another way to make them work?

Comment: "can the certificates provided in network security config used to configure wifi/vpn" -- not that I am aware of. AFAICT, the network security configuration is purely for HTTPS.

Comment: I don't understand why would you want to have dynamic addition of trusted certs. Normally you should only trust in your CA certificate that can sign how many certificates you need. As you trust in this CA (by adding it to the network security config in Android N), all the dynamic certificates signed by this CA shall be trusted by your application.